# twitter bootstrap btn-group to drive tab content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am trying to implement tabbed content using bootstraps btn-group. I have some working code, but am not sure it is the best way to go about it.

HTML:

```
<section class="section" id="tabContent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <div class="btn btn-inverse active tabber" id="submission-div">
                        <label for="submission">Submission</label>
                        <input type="radio" checked="" id="submission">
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn btn-inverse tabber" id="rules-div">
                        <label for="rules">Rules</label>
                        <input type="radio" checked="" id="rules">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="submission-content">
            <h1>Submission content</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="rules-content" class="hide">
            <h1>Rules</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.tabber',function(e){
    if ($("#submission-div").hasClass("active")) {
        $("#submission-content").addClass("hide");
        $("#rules-content").removeClass("hide");
    }else if ($("#rules-div").hasClass("active")){
        $("#rules-content").addClass("hide");
        $("#submission-content").removeClass("hide");
    }
});
```

This JQuery onClick callback works, doesn't make sense when you read it. I think this is because this FXN is fired off before the active class has been updated in the markup.

I was hoping for a better way to accomplish tab content, hopefully with out changing the markup too much cause the styling is correct for the markup.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!
A

Comment: Why not just use bootstrap's tabs plugin? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the [Bootstrap Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) with `data-toggle="tab"` and `data-target=` attributes? (no jQuery needed)..

**Demo:** http://www.bootply.com/ZueoFI9iFC

```
<section class="section" id="tabContent">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-group-justified" 
                     data-toggle="buttons">
                    <div class="btn btn-inverse active tabber" id="submission-div"
                         data-toggle="tab" data-target="#submission-content">
                        <label for="submission">Submission</label>
                        <input type="radio" checked="" id="submission"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn btn-inverse tabber" id="rules-div" 
                         data-toggle="tab" data-target="#rules-content">
                        <label for="rules">Rules</label>
                        <input type="radio" checked="" id="rules"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="submission-content" class="tab-pane active">
                <h1>Submission content</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="rules-content" class="tab-pane">
                <h1>Rules</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there's likely a cleaner overall solution, but if you're wanting to just have your JQ make sense and change as little as possible, you can do this:

```
$(".tabber").click(function(){
 if ($(this).is("#submission-div")) {
     $("#submission-content").removeClass("hide");
     $("#rules-content").addClass("hide");
 }else if ($(this).is("#rules-div")){
     $("#rules-content").removeClass("hide");
     $("#submission-content").addClass("hide");
 }
});
```